# Can someone Help me Identify this Font?

Tags: font-identification, serif

[image][image: Typewriter]

This is the font that i can't manage to identify.. or to find a close one.
If someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: counterfeiting money? ;-)

Comment: lool no ... is a thermal printing font.

Comment: You can always go to http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to upload a portion of your image and what the font will try to find best possible matches. Hope this will help you for your future font identification.

Answer (score 5):

It's basically Courier:

[image: Courier New]

but produced on a fairly crude dot-matrix printer. The letter forms are a product of the way they are produced.

MyFonts has [a number of dot-matrix fonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/dot+matrix/fonts/) and [**Vactic**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/vactic/) might be a reasonable alternative which is **quite** close, if you don't want to create your own:

[image: Vactic]

Comment: no (to your matrix font), look at the `A`

Comment: @Wolf OK, "match" was meant to imply matched **function** (Courier-**like** dot-matrix) rather than an exact match in **form**.

Comment: Ok, I see. (Seems really Courier +1)

Comment: Thanks ... basically Courier seems close inaf ... but with the dot part ... hmm ... the picture i uploaded are in zoom because if you are not looking close you don't see the dots.

Comment: the actual font dimension is 11.

Comment: @blackice2x If you go to the MyFonts link in the answer, you'll see a number of alternatives. I just picked one I thought relevant. But there's even one called [Fake Receipt](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/fake-receipt/)!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that you will find it as a ready font. It was done via printing matrix. In past (when we need something similar) we just reconstruct it from circles and created own font.

Comment: :) now that is something that i can't do :) .. but thanks ..i'm still hoping. ... I found one that is similar.. http://www.dafont.com/rough-typewriter.font?af=on&text=REVISIONE+DEL+1280649 ... but not the same.

Comment: It is completely another :) if you want to do it right - you need to reconstruct letters you need with dots to imitate matrix printing head. Paint bleeding will do all the rest for you.

Comment: Yep, it's a custom font. If anything - you can use Lexia or Foro Medium as a base.